# How can I get file creation dates in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, fileinfo

I'm trying to get the file list sorted by creation dates for a bunch of xlsx files in the folder `ad_dir='C:\AT files\'`. Using the Matlab `dir` function will give me the last modified dates which is no good for me.

I've tried running the following Python code:

```py
flist = py.sorted(py.glob.glob([ad_dir '*.xlsx']),'key',py.os.path.getctime, 'reverse',True);
```

but I keep getting Python Error:

> TypeError: getctime() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

I'm using Matlab R2018a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method from .Net's `System` ( [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=net-7.0#system-io-file-getcreationtime(system-string)) ).

This can be done directly within MATLAB as if is was a MATLAB function because the library you need should already be loaded, see the [MATLAB docs for calling .NET](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/access-a-simple-net-class.html)

```
fullpath = 'C:\FolderA\FolderB\MyFile.xlsx';
c = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(fullpath);
```

`c` is a structure with all of the components needed for `datetime` if you want, e.g.

```
created = datetime(c.Year, c.Month, c.Day, c.Hour, c.Minute, c.Second);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does your solution allow for wildcards e.g. *.xlsx ? I'm trying to obtain the latest file created in a folder containing multiple files.

Comment: Use `dir` with wildcards to get your file list then run this on each file